# Android BLE how to send message with GATT?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to communicate with JDY-18 Bluetooth module using Android BLE (Java). Currently, I can connect with JDY-18 but I can't send message to it. I get problem while use this:  `mBluetoothGatt.getService` this is some snippets of my program:
Firstly, I get UUIDList of JDY-18:

```
public void startScanning() {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions.toArray(new String[0]));
                return;
            }
            btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
        }
    });
}


// Device scan callback.


private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions.toArray(new String[0]));
                return;
            }
    

            if (result.getDevice().getName() != null) {

                if (result.getDevice().getName().equals("JDY-18")) {
                    targetDevAddr = result.getDevice().getAddress();
                    tvAppend(tv_read, "\r\nSet targetDevAddr to " + targetDevAddr);

//                    Add this to get UUIDList
                    serviceUUIDsList = getServiceUUIDsList(result);
                    stopScanning();
                }
            }
        }
    };

private List<UUID> getServiceUUIDsList(ScanResult scanResult)
    {
        List<ParcelUuid> parcelUuids = scanResult.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids();

        List<UUID> serviceList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parcelUuids.size(); i++)
        {
            UUID serviceUUID = parcelUuids.get(i).getUuid();

            if (!serviceList.contains(serviceUUID))
                serviceList.add(serviceUUID);
        }

        return serviceList;
    }
```

I get 2 UUIDs:

> 0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
>
> 0000fee7-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Then, I get service:

```
BluetoothGattService service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
if (service == null) {
        tvAppend(tv_read,"\r\nService not found!");
    }
service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000fee7-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
if (service == null) {
        tvAppend(tv_read,"\r\nService not found!");
    }
```

And output are:

> Service not found!
>
> Service not found!

I also set permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
```

Did I missing something ? Please help me to figure out the problem.

Thank you so much !

Comment: Based on the source code you provided you never connect to the device. You need to connect and start a service discovery before using the services

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKotzjan, thanks for your advice. May you give me some quotes about thís case ? I very appreciate that.

Comment: You could go through the android documentation about BLE: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-ble-devices They add the found devices to a list. Since you only want to connect to your device you could connect to it immediately. Simply follow their steps :)

Comment: It worked. Thanks @MichaelKotzjan. Please answer the question and i will mark it as correctly. BTW I'm facing with new issue about read characteristic. At bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristicRead); It return false. I know only one read, write action is implemented at a time. So when start app I do readCharacteristic first. I also do discovery service before. And characteristicRead is correctly. Cuz I use another app also use it. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Glad I could help! Regarding your other problem: It would be best to ask a new question including all the details necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing a BLE device you need to follow a few steps:

1. Find the device by calling `bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);`. The found devices are reported through the callback `leScanCallback`.
2. Connect to the device using `bluetoothService.connect(deviceAddress);`
3. After you connected successfully call `bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();` to find all available services the devices provides.

These steps are always necessary before reading or writing a characteristic. You are currently only doing step 1. Please refer to the official [Bluetooth Low Energy Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/ble-overview) for more information and sample code snippets.